# Insert differences between 2 tables into 3rd table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have total of 3 tables in my database.

My Testing1 and Testing2 table have two exact columns (ItemID and ItemPath). My Testing3 have three columns (ItemID, ItemPath and Source).

I'm trying to compare ***Testing1*** with ***Testing2*** and insert the difference to Testing3.

I'm able get the the difference but I'm just wondering how can modify it to meet this scenario.

***For Example.***

If Item is only existed in ***Testing1*** then insert it into Testing3 table with
"***Testing1***" as Source column value.

If Item is only existed in ***Testing2*** then insert it into Testing3 table with
"***Testing2***" as Source column value.

```
INSERT INTO Testing3 (ItemId, ItemPath, Source)
SELECT pm.ItemID, pm.ItemPath
FROM Testing1 pm
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ec.ItemId
FROM Testing2 ec
WHERE ec.ItemID = pm.ItemID);
```

Comment: A useful way to find the differences between two sets is `except`

Comment: Since you are on sql 2012 I’d just use the tablediff.exe tool that is used by replication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to combine your results for insert. And add a static value for `Source`.

```
INSERT INTO Testing3 (ItemId, ItemPath, Source)
SELECT pm.ItemID, pm.ItemPath, 'Testing1'
FROM Testing1 pm
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ec.ItemId
    FROM Testing2 ec
    WHERE ec.ItemID = pm.ItemID
)
UNION ALL
SELECT pm.ItemID, pm.ItemPath, 'Testing2'
FROM Testing2 pm
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ec.ItemId
    FROM Testing1 ec
    WHERE ec.ItemID = pm.ItemID
)
```